# How do I only add an image to my main UINavigationController?

Tags: image, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have the option to print in the app I am working on which is where I am getting my issue

If I add in the code for adding an image to the NavigationBar...

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (UINavigationBarCategory)  

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect  
{  
      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];  

      [image drawInRect:rect];  
}  

@end
```

It also adds the image to the navigationBar on my UIPrintController popup view.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Place that category only in the file that you want it to affect, make sure it isn't getting imported into the popup view at any place.